# Passing a variable to lightning component through snapin chat

Tags: lightning, liveagent, javascript-controller, snap-ins

I have a snapin chat component embedded on our custom application (not salesforce or a community). I'm trying to allow a parameter to pass through to my lightning component for use in the prechat screen - i.e. given the user is logged in to our application (again, not salesforce), we want to say 'Hello {{firstName}}'.

I'm aware of the embedded_svc.settings.prepopulatedPrechatFields snippet (although I can't seem to get it to work), so I'm hoping I could pass information through there to leverage in my component.

Am I going about the solution incorrectly? Should I be going about this through some other javascript method? Is this even feasible without having the hosting application write the information to the component after runtime?